# How to cancel setTimeout action after it has been triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `JavaScript` I have some code that is executed when the page is loaded/reloaded. What it does is to click a hidden button so that 30 seconds after the page is loaded/reloaded, a pop-up window appears:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#colorboxpopupform').click();
}, 30000);
```

The problem is that I also have another button that triggers that same pop-up window. This means that if someone loads/reloads the page and after 15 seconds clicks the button to load the pop-up window, the following code will make the same window to pop-up to be displayed again because the 30 seconds counter is still in process:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#colorboxpopupform').click();
}, 30000);
```

What I need is that the code above opens the pop-up window after 30 seconds, only if I have not used my other button that triggers that same pop-up window. In other words, if the user explicitly clicks the button that triggers the pop-up window, I want for the code above to not trigger the pop-up window after 30 seconds anymore (cancel the action). How could I achieve that with `JavaScript`/`jQuery`? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

I used the following solution, as Patrick P suggested in his answer, and it works:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("displaypopup") == "true") {
    var ticker = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#colorboxpopupform').click();
    }, 30000);
}
$("#headercolorboxpopupform").click(
    function() {
        clearTimeout(ticker);
    }
);
```

Comment: In the future it will likely be faster to simply google "cancel settimeout", as the answer is readily available online

Comment: @AndyRay Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya Questions shouldn't be edited to include solutions. Especially questions closed because they're duplicates.

Comment: @Sean I don't know where else to write my solution. It is relevant and it includes stuff not provided in that same way in the answers to linked questions. I accepted for this question to be marked as duplicate but there were a few differences in the approach I was using with `JavaScript` and `jQuery`, so I find it relevant to share what I did to solve my own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout()` to cancel the timeout:

```
const ticker = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#colorboxpopupform').click();
}, 30000);
```

Call `clearTimeout(ticker)` when needed.

[Documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)